# How to correctly retrieve records from a many to many relationship (Doctrine - DQL query)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following DQL query:

```
$qb->select('v, b, c, t, p, m, s, f, h')
    ->from('UrlBuilderBundle:Version', 'v')
    ->leftJoin('v.ddlBrands', 'b', 'WITH', 'b.version = v.id AND b.isActive = 1 AND v.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('v.ddlCampaignObjectives', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.version = v.id AND c.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('v.ddlThemes', 't', 'WITH', 't.version = v.id AND t.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('t.ddlProducts', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('v.ddlMediums', 'm', 'WITH', 'm.version = v.id AND m.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('m.ddlSources', 's', 'WITH', 's.ddlMedium = m.id AND s.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('v.fields', 'f', 'WITH', 'f.version = v.id AND f.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('f.helpText', 'h', 'WITH', 'h.field = f.id AND h.isActive = 1');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$versions = $query->getArrayResult();
```

All of the specified joins are between tables that have a many to one/one to many relationship except between the ddlProducts and ddlThemes tables. There is a many to many relationship (ddlProducts and ddlThemes) which is causing problems, it results in the following error:

> Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded at
>   /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:296)"}

Can anyone point me in the right direction in resolving this error?

Comment: the error its in php so you have to incrise php time execuetaion in php.ini max_execution_time

Comment: I don't want to go down this route. I want to optimise the query so it doesn't take as long to run.

Comment: You should debug and check if query is working properly or not...
For that temporarily  add => "set_time_limit(0);"
If query executes successfully then i think we can optimize afterwards

Comment: can you put the result of this query 
use getOneOrNullResult yo avoid max time execution  error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, querying and populating collections of 9 different interconnected entities will do that.
But without more knowledge of your entire model, we cannot say what can be changed in the query.

Perhaps you can try finding tables that can be denormalized into some other one to avoid the extra join.
Or perhaps you could split the query in more if you do not need everything in one uber table.

It really depends on what you need the resultset for

Comment: The result set is used by an AJAX call to populate select elements in a form.

Comment: In that case, you probably do not need everything in one huge table. You can retrieve the tables on separate queries and return them in a single array to avoid extra ajax calls. You probably do not need entire objects either. Just select the fields you need

Answer (score 0):

Hyradrate complex resultset into object tree is expensive operation. As input size grows (more rows from database) and as you join more entities into tree (many-to-many associations), it takes ORM more and more time to build object tree. In mathematics your problem describes [Bachmann–Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

You can try to so-called [Multi-step Hydration](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/doctrine-orm-optimization-hydration/).